# jQuery selector for first appearance of span in td

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-filter

I have the following HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span></span></td>
        <td><a><span></span></a></td>
        <td><span></span><span><span/></td>
    </tr>
<table/>
```

I need to select the first appearance of span in each td. 
I would exepcted 3 spans from the above HTML.

`$('td span')` returns all (4) spans

`$('td span:first-child')` return all spans also

`$('td span:first')` return only first

`$('td > span')` return only 2 spans.

Could I do this by selector or filter?
What do I have to use to achieve this?

Comment: I write here only example "abstract" html. In my app I have all necessary tags

Comment: please provide perfect html to get perfect answer

Comment: @elnino3800: I fixed your HTML. In future it would not be a good idea to say "This is my HTML" but post completly invalid made up un-usable HTML. It could lead to confusion and replies might advise you that your issue is because of invalid HTML.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
​$('td').find('span:first')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qDAt8/

Please note that your markup is not valid.

Comment: +1, nice one, you are on the ball. Haven't seen your reply. Always a step ahead :)

Answer (score 2):

After fixing the HTML, this will work:

```
$('td').find('span:first');
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xxn2H/)

The DEMO above uses the following sample HTML and visualy highlights the matching elements:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span>span 1.1</span><span>span 1.2</span></td>
        <td><a><span>span 2.1</span><span>span 2.2</span></a></td>
        <td><span>span 3.1</span><span>span 3.2</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("table td").find("span:first")
```

Gives you the three first spans. jQuery finds element more efficiently when you provide a more detailed search.